# Insert data from sql file when call hook_schema on drupal 7

Tags: database

I developed a module in drupal 7 that need a database table like "example_table". And i create "example_table" table using example_schema() function. Now I need to insert some default data.

Here, I can use `drupal_write_record('example_table', $data);` function to insert data into `example_install()` function.

But, I want to insert data from example_db.sql file.

How can I do it? Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, hope it helps.

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$sql = file_get_contents('file.sql');
$qr = $db->exec($sql);
```

Otherwise try this, but i am also not aware of this correctly,

```
function my_module_install() {
  // Get the contents of the .sql file.
  $sql = file_get_contents(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/module.sql');
  // Split into individual statements based on new lines.
  $statements = preg_split('/[\n\r]+/', $sql);
  foreach ($statements as $query) {
    db_query($query);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Reddy, your first solution working... :), I update my question with answer, for first commer...

Comment: Hi @A Ajay Kumar Reddy, sorry for removing ans mark. I m working with drupal, maybe drupal has their own system without declaring username and password. So, i just need insert data without declaring username and password.